# 100D dice game - chance of losing

Tags: probability

In a dice game you use one 100-sided die and you must roll seven 1's or 2's (not necessarily consecutively) followed by rolling a 1. My question is what are the chances of rolling exactly seven 1s or 2s but never the final roll of 1 in a game of rolling the die 3600 times in total?

What I've tried so far:
So far with my thinking I think we need to know where the last successful 1/50 roll is on the road to 3600 total rolls. So I've calculated each of (1/50)<sup>7</sup> * (49/50)<sup>n</sup> * (99/100)<sup>3600-7-n</sup> , for n = 0 to 3593. And then multiplied each by a weight which is the combinations available of having the 7th 1/50 roll in that amount of total rolls. For example getting the 7th 1/50 on the 7th roll has one combination for all the 1/50 rolls, that is (7 choose7). And the combinations for the 7th on the 8th total roll are 7 because we can fail a roll in any one of the 1st -7th roll and still get our final on the 8th. And if we think about it the combinations available are just the new ones when we add one more total die rolls. So the combinations are (n choose 7) - ((n-1) choose 7) where n is the number of total rolls. So after I've multiplied each term in the sum of 3600 terms by their individual weights, and then added them up, I've then divided off the total sum of the weights to get the final probability of gettning exactly seven 1/50 dice rolls but not the final 1/100 in 3600 total rolls which was 3.5e-36

I think this is wrong but I'm not sure where. If I add on the probability of getting exacly 0 to 6 of the 1/50 rolls (which is more trivial) we get the total probability of losing the game, and if I change the total rolls to 450 which is how many we would to expect to win the game, I actually get a losing probability of only 0.2 :(

Comment: Where does this game come from? [It might be of interest for some to look at what is already known about it.]

Comment: Sorry, I made up the game. The point is that you need seven 1/50 dice rolls followed by a 1/100 dice roll to beat the game. But I want to know what the chances are of getting exactly seven 1/50 rolls without getting the final 1/100, with 3600 total rolls. -Because I don't know how to work it out and I want to be able to. (unfortunately the problem could be a computer rounding error in code, if my logic is sound?).

Answer (score 1):

Given any $k\geq7$ positions for the $1$s and $2$s, there are $2^7$ ways to get the first seven, but the rest must all be $2.$ And there are $98^{3600-k}$ results for the other rolls. So the probability is $$\frac{2^7}{100^{3600}} \sum_{k=7}^{3600} \binom{3600}k98^{3600-k}$$ which is equivalent to:

$$\frac{2^7}{100^{3600}}\left(99^{3600}-\sum_{k=0}^{6}\binom{3600}{k}98^{3600-k}\right)$$

or:

$${2^7}\left(\left(\frac{99}{100}\right)^{3600}-\left(\frac{98}{100}\right)^{3600}\sum_{k=0}^{6}\binom{3600}{k}98^{-k}\right)$$

An upper bound is $$2^7(99/100)^{3600}\approx\frac1{4\times 10^{13}}$$

I think the minus terms are negligible. Certainly, $$2^7(98/100)^{3600}<\frac{1}{3\times 10^{29}}$$

The largest term in the subtraction sum is $$\binom{3600}{6}98^{-6}\leq \frac{1}{6!}\left(\frac{3600}{98}\right)^6<3.5\times10^{6}.$$

So the subtracted term is at most:

$$7\cdot 3.5\times10^{6}\frac{1}{3\times10^{29}}<\frac{1}{10^{22}}$$

Comment: +1 for the approximation. $2^7(99/100)^{3600}$ looks about $1.34 \times 10^{-23}$ too high which is, as you say, negligible

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought that if the seventh $1$ or $2$ appears on the $n$th roll then the probability of this and then never hitting a $1$ again is $${n-1 \choose 6}\frac{49^{n-7}}{50^{n-1}}\times \frac1{50} \times \left(\frac{99}{100}\right)^{3600-n}$$

For example with $n=600$ this gives about $4\times 10^{-17}$

Sum these over $n$, for example with the R code

```
n <- 1:3600
probs <-  exp( lchoose(n-1,6) +(n-7)*log(49) -n*log(50) +(3600-n)*log(99/100) )
sum(probs)
```

and you get about $2.476912\times 10^{-14}$

Thomas Andrew's bound of $2^7(99/100)^{3600}$ is extremely close: a difference smaller than $10^{-22}$